# How to override a property to be non-nullable in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

The DefinitelyTyped definition of the Node built-in IncomingMessage (the type of req in the `(req, res, next)` arguments) has defined [`url` to be nullable](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4d672cbbd775375ea2cdca5c0f8a5ae31f6fa80f/node/node.d.ts#L675-L678). Here's the snipped parts of the definition file:

```
// @types/node/index.d.ts
declare module "http" {
  export interface IncomingMessage {
    /**
     * Only valid for request obtained from http.Server.
     */
    url?: string;
  }
}
```

As the comment says, this is because this property is only valid when you're getting an instance of this IncomingMessage from the http.Server. In other uses it won't exist, hence, it's nullable.

However, in my case, *I know* that I'm only getting these instances from http.Server, and so it's kinda annoying that I can't just access the property without extra guards.

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';

function someMiddleware(req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse, next: Function) {
  const myStr: string = req.url; // bzzzt.
  // Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not
  // assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
}
```

*It's probably good to mention that I'm using TS 2.0.3 with `strictNullChecks`, which is not enabled on the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).*

Here's the question. **Is it possible to override that definition across my application so that `url` is not nullable?**

---

Here's what I've already tried... adding this to one of my files:

```
declare module 'http' {
  interface IncomingMessage {
    url: string;
  }
}
```

...however that is disallowed: "Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type". [This is explained in the documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

The only thing I can think of thus far is to create my own module which imports, extends and then exports the interfaces:

```
// /src/http.ts
import { IncomingMessage as OriginalIM } from 'http';
export interface IncomingMessage extends OriginalIM {
  url: string;
}

// src/myapp.ts
import { IncomingMessage } from './http'; // <-- local def

function someMiddleware(req: IncomingMessage) {
  const str: string = req.url; // all good
}
```

So, this works, but it seems so wrong.

Comment: IMO what you did is not wrong provided you are sure this object property is always present. Certainly better than casting this type everywhere in the code.

Answer (score 38):

As of TypeScript 2.1, you can use a lookup type to access an interface property.

```
IncomingMessage['url'] // string | undefined
```

You can combine that with [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to fit your use case.

```
NonNullable<IncomingMessage['url']> // string
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Answer (score 25):

So I found a solution which is *slightly* less hacky.

TypeScript 2.0 also has added a [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator): `!`

```
function someMiddleware(req: IncomingMessage) {
  const str1: string = req.url;  // error, can't assign string | undefined to string
  const str2: string = req.url!; // works
}
```

In my case, it's still a bit annoying, since there are many different files which need to access this property and so this non-null assertion is used in many places.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! I only add for others that may not follow your link, that the `!` operator asserts both *non-null* and *non-undefined*.

Comment: This operator should be used only `in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact`, for because of the business logic. Using it everywhere as a rule can be confusing.

Answer (score 22):

In your sample case, it's easy because you want to get rid of ALL `undefined`, therefore use the `Required` utility type.

```
interface IncomingMessage { url?: string; }
type ValidMessage = Required<IncomingMessage>;
```

ValidMessage will have all properties `required`.

But for those coming here to find out how to get rid of ALL `null`, you can use this custom utility type.

```
export type NonNullableFields<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]>;
};

interface IncomingMessage { url: string | null; }
type ValidMessage = NonNullableFields<IncomingMessage>;
```

ValidMessage will have all properties `not null`.

And for those coming here to find out how to get rid of `null` only for specific fields, you can use these custom utility types.

```
export type NonNullableFields<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]>;
};

export type NonNullableField<T, K extends keyof T> = T &
NonNullableFields<Pick<T, K>>;

interface IncomingMessage { url: string | null; }
type ValidMessage = NonNullableField<IncomingMessage, 'url'>;
```

ValidMessage will have the property `url` `not null`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution defining a utility type `RequiredProperties`:

```
type RequiredProperties<T, P extends keyof T> = Omit<T, P> & Required<Pick<T, P>>;
```

Example usage:

```
type Foo = {
    a?: any;
    b?: any;
    c?: any;
};

type Bar = RequiredProperties<Foo, 'a' | 'b'>;

const bar1: Bar = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const bar2: Bar = { b: 2, c: 3 }; // fails because `a` is now required
const bar3: Bar = { c: 3 }; // fails because both `a` and `b` are missing
```