# TypeScript guard for nullable type doesn't work

Tags: typescript

Why guard for nullable type doesn't work in this case?

```
interface Person { name?: string }
let alex = {} as Person

function welcome(person: { name: string }) {}

if (alex.name != null) {
  s = alex.name          // Works nicely, no error here, 
                         // it knows that alex.name isn't null

  welcome(alex)          // Wrongly complains here 
                         // that `alex.name` could be null
}
```

You need to enable `strictNullCheck` compiler option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override a property to be non-nullable in Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370214/how-to-override-a-property-to-be-non-nullable-in-typescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not `alex.name` is null, the types `{ name?: string }` and `{ name: string }` aren't compatible.

You can do this:

```
function hasName(person: Person): person is { name: string } {
    return person.name != null;
}

if (hasName(alex)) {
    welcome(alex);
}
```

---

#### Edit

It might be an overkill, but that's how [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) work.
You can of course just type assert it:

```
welcome(alex as { name: string });
```

Comment: Check my revised answer