# How to transform the selected options from a form into a payload object without the need of the bang operator?

Tags: typescript

I have a form input developed in React that have several fields and a "Send" button. The button should only be enabled when all the required fields are filled. After pressing "Send", I want to transform the inputted information into a new payload so I can send it to my backend.

The problem is, the input properties could be null if the user hasn't inputted anything yet. But when I hit "Send", I'm sure that these properties are not null anymore, as the button is only enabled when the inputs are filled. But when transforming my selected options into my payload I don't see a way of not using the bang operator, as Typescript is not aware that I have already validated the required inputs.

Here is a simplified example of the code.

```js
interface SelectedOptions {
  userInfo: {
    name: string | null;
    age: number | null
  };
  address: string | null;
}

interface Payload {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string | null;
}

const validateOptions = (options: SelectedOptions) => {
  return options.name && options.age;
}

const transformOptionsIntoPayload = (options: SelectedOptions) => {
  // If this method is being called, I'm sure that "options" have all the required fields filled.
  const payload: Payload = {
    name: options.userInfo.name!, // Bang operator
    age: options.userInfo.age!, // Bang operator
    address: options.address
  }
  return payload;
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this situation? Or should I just ignore es-lint's warning about the bang operator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to let the TS compiler know that the supplied input conforms with your desired type.

```
const validateOptions = (options: SelectedOptions):options is Payload => !!(options.name && options.age)
```

Then in your code

```
if (validateOptions(formData)) {
  // formData inside your if will be treated as Payload
}
```

Comment: You mean to use the type guard on ```transformOptionsIntoPayload ```, right? Besides, I may have simplified the example a bit too much. The SelectedOptions and Payload interfaces does not have the same fields, it could be nested in SelectedOptions. I edited it to make it a little more complex.

Comment: I understand. Manually writing the type-guard would be an overkill.
In that case I would recommend using a runtime validator such as zod, yup, io-ts etc to do the type checks for me.
I would avoid using the bang operator as it would most probably bite me at a later time

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @Gustavo Cesário,

In my opinion, the `non-null assertion` operator is not my preferred choice. If given the option, I would rather use the `optional chaining` operator for the same purpose `(?.)` to safely access properties of an object that may be `null` or `undefined`. Like `user?.name`. That just things for that option. So, I just add that here.

Alternatively, I'm using `Required<SelectedOptions>` with `as` keyword with **nullish coalescing operator** to provide default values for any properties that are `null` or `undefined`.

```
const transformOptionsIntoPayload = (options: SelectedOptions) => {
  const requiredOptions = options as Required<SelectedOptions>;
  const payload: Payload = {
    name: requiredOptions.userInfo.name ?? '',
    age: requiredOptions.userInfo.age ?? 0,
    address: requiredOptions.address ?? ''
  };
  return payload;
}
```

TypeScript will treat the `options` object as if it has all the required fields filled on that way.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the problem. I tried to call ```validateOptions``` before generating my payload but typescript is not aware that this method assured that the required fields are not null. ```TS18047: 'opcoesSelecionadas.abertura' is possibly 'null'.```

Comment: Okay. So, @Gustavo Cesário. I'm finds my works, you can see the answer now.

Comment: Hmm, Required seems to only remove "undefined" properties from the object. I found a similar implementation for "null" properties, what do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370214/how-to-override-a-property-to-be-non-nullable-in-typescript

Comment: In that case, how about using ***nullish coalescing operator*** like that 
```const payload: Payload = { name: options.userInfo.name ?? '', age: options.userInfo.age ?? 0, address: options.address ?? '' };``` @GustavoCesário

Comment: Thanks for giving idea about ***nullish coalescing operator***. Now check my answer.